# Regex to match a single word only

Tags: regex

EDIT: Using python to read csv file and output based on regex

Matches should be

```
OPS
ops
-OPS/
```

But not

```
OPS\

1OPS2

1OPS

1 OPS

OPS2

OPS 2
```

Trying to create regex that matches

```
OPS
```

with

```
(?:\b|\d|_|-)OPS(?:\b|\d|_|-)
```

Unfortunately it also matches

1. Admin OPS\fiscal
2. Admin OPS

How to create a regex that will match only if OPS is by itself in a line?

Comment: So you just want to match lines that only contain OPS and nothing else?
 `^OPS$`

Comment: It will be helpful to explain what you are really doing and what tool you are using.

Comment: Yeah, it's a simple question as stated, but I'm hesitant to add an answer because there's so much weirdness going on in the regex that you provided. It suggests that you're looking for something else. Do you also want to match something like `123OPS456` or `_OPS_`?

Comment: You may use `(?i)(?<=[/-])ops(?=[/-])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this pattern:

`(?i)^[\/-]?OPS[\/-]?$`

https://regex101.com/r/EcYizT/1

Explanation:

`(?i)` - Enables case-insensitive mode

`^` - Anchor point at the beginning of the line

`[\/-]?` - Optionally match either a hyphen or a forward slash

`OPS` - Literal string

`[\/-]?` - Another optional hyphen or forward slash

`$` Anchor point at the end of the line